# JavaScript append string with element(s)

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, selectors-api

I'm trying to use more and more native Javascript code in stead of jQuery. If I want to append a string with html elements in another classified elements with jQuery it's very easy:

```
<div class='destination'></div>
<div class='destination'></div>

var selector = "class='svg_element'";
var svgElement = "<svg " + selector + " ></svg>";

$(".destination").append(svgElement);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RfFLW/)

**How can I do this with short code in native JavaScript (without using a loop)?**

I tried a lot, for example my simply thoughts:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".destination").appendChild(svgElement);
```

Maybe something with creating the element first:

var svg = document.createElement("svg");

```
//works
document.querySelector(".destination").appendChild(svg);

//doesn't works
document.querySelectorAll(".destination").appendChild(svg);
```

Comment: `I'm trying to use more and more native Javascript code in stead of jQuery.` Why?

Comment: What is `selector` in your first example? Incidentally, to do the same thing to multiple elements (as `querySelectorAll()` returns an HTMLCollection) you need to iterate over those returned elements.

Comment: If it was that easy then there would be libraries like jquery.

Comment: @Matt Burland Because it's often quicker and svg manipulation works easier and better with Javascript. And I don't wanna create multiple objects to support jQuery and Javascript functions.

Comment: @David Thomas I forgot, for example a class or id property.

Comment: Why without using a loop? You are performing a transform on a collection of items. Even if you ended up in a one-liner, what do you think happens in the code behind? jQuery uses no sorcery either (http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.appendTo)

Comment: @karlipoppins yes I see, good link. Why without? Because I need it very often. With your comment I think I will write my own function for it to keep short code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll(".destination"),
    function (node) { node.appendChild(svg); }
);
```

Now save it for later:

```
NodeList.prototype.append = function (child) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this, function (parent) {
        parent.appendChild(child);
    }); 
};
```

But don't do [that](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Do this instead:

```
var appendToNodeList = function (nodelist, child) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodelist, function (parent) {
        parent.appendChild(child);
    }); 
};

appendToNodeList(document.querySelectorAll(".destination"), svg);
```